# Get name/value from field Type "Name Lookup Value List" in Sitecore 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore, sitecore7, namevaluecollection, sitecore7.1

I am using Sitecore 7.1 . I used one field  Type  **"Name Lookup value List"** . I want catch name/value stored in that Field Type in Code behind in MVC . How  can I catch the Key value Item .

Answer (score 10):

```
string keyValueRawValue = item["NameValueListFieldName"];
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(keyValueRawValue );

foreach (string key in nameValueCollection ) 
{
      var value = nv[key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. But the given solution return only Value ,i want Value with its corresponding Key.